# Scheme - Syntax of optional arguments in a method call

Tags: oop, arguments, scheme, optional-parameters

I'm looking at some additional exercise from an introductory course on programming, this is from a section on OOP with Scheme.

I have -circle- defined as an object with argument radius.
Also, I have area defined as being a method of -circle-.

```
(define -circle-
  (lambda (r)
    (define area (lambda () (* pi r r)))
    (lambda (method-name)
      (cond
        ((eq? method-name 'area) area)
        (else (error '-circle- "Method not found: ~s" method-name))
        ))))
```

I have call defined as a function applying optional arguments to the method of an object.
(I'm not sore about the syntax here, but this was a given and I think I understand the meaning as: "first apply the method to the object, if you have arguments, put them in too").

```
(define call
  (lambda (obj method-name . args)
    (apply (obj method-name) args)))
```

The test example (perfectly working in DrRacket/Pretty Big) is:

```
(define c1 (-circle- 3))
(call c1 'area)
```

but as I see it, this closure would bring to:

```
(call -circle- 3 'area)
```

instead of:

```
(call -circle- 'area . 3)
```

(which in turn leads to an `illegal use of '.'` error).

Could someone clarify how input with optional arguments actually works in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you should know is the dot notation binds zero or more items to the name after the dot as a list.

```
(define (exmaple a b .c) c)
(example 1 2 3 4 5) --> (3 4 5)
```

Secondly defines arent' textual, unless you use a literal. When you define x to by y, y is evaluated before being associated with x. C1 isn't `'(-circle- 3)` it's the result of evaluating -circle- with the argument three, which is the function `(lambda (method-name) ...)` within an enviroment where the variable called radius is 3.

So what `(call c1 'area)` does is evaluate `((lambda (method-name) ...) 'area)` where radius is three. It returns `(lambda () (* pi r r))` where radius is 3. Apply then applies that function to the null list (which is fitting as the function has no formal arguments) which returns the result of 9*pi

Answer (score 2):

The result of `(-circle- 3)` is the same as this:

```
(lambda (method-name)
  (cond ((eq? method-name 'area) area)
        (else (error '-circle- "Method not found: ~s" method-name))))
```

with `area` set to `(lambda () (* pi 3 3))`. That means that the return value of `((-circle- 3) 'area)` is also `(lambda () (* pi 3 3))`.

A call to `(call (-circle- 3) 'area)` has the same effect as `(apply ((-circle- 3) 'area) '())` (since the rest arguments, `args`, is empty), which is the same as evaluating `(((-circle- 3) 'area))`, which we know is the same as `((lambda () (* pi 3 3)))`, which evaluates to `(* pi 3 3)`.

Note: `(call (-circle- 3) 'area)` is *not* the same as `(call -circle- 3 'area)`.

Comment: I'd choose both answers, but I chosed WorBlux's as he/she has less points.

Comment: @maja What do you mean less? They have 824 and I have 114! ;-) ;-) ;-)